# Problems in Kentico, doesnt find CMSItem reference

Tags: c#, kentico

we had some movements of some webservices yesterday in our project. We had the web services in trunk of SVN, we created a branch for them because we want to use the webservices in our website in the branch too.

Ok, after to do it I am getting the next error: looks like doesnt find CMSItem just when I run the webseite.

We have a Kentico version 7

[image]

Why it is happening? where can I find the reference? Is possible our kentico liscence is for only one directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kentico 8, `CMSItem` lives in the [CMS.Helpers](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/8_0/api/html/N_CMS_Helpers.htm) namespace.

You're using **v7**, where it lives under `CMS.GlobalHelper`.

E.g.

```
CMS.GlobalHelper.CMSItem
```

Make sure you've referenced the `CMS.GlobalHelper.dll` in your project.

See [API docs](http://devnet.kentico.com/documentation/older-documentation)

```
Kentico 7 > Reference Guides > Kentico CMS API reference > CHM file
```

[image]

Comment: I have this using: `using CMS.CMSHelper;` it fails in GetResource.ash.cs

Comment: and in bin I have as reference `CMS.CMSHelpers.dll`